# Amazon AWS Architectural Flow

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a flow problem that I was hoping for some help with:

User Request -> Route 53 -> Cloudfront -> Elastic Load Balancer -> EC2 Instance -> Nginx -> App Server - {calculates a URL to download an S3 asset} -> {returns the X-Accel-Redirect header with the URL from S3} -> Nginx -> {pulls apart and re-assembles the X-Accel-Redirect header back into the S3 URL} -> S3 Asset -> Cloudfront -> User Agent!

So, this works fine if I make a request to the Elastic Load Balancer or the EC2 instance directly, but as soon as I try and make the request through Cloudfront (either by pointing Cloudfront at the ELB or directly at an EC2 Instance), I get back the SignatureDoesNotMatch XML response and no asset.

Does anyone have an idea why accessing the S3 assets through Cloudfront would cause this issue?

Comment: I don't understand the use of Cloudfront here at all.

Comment: if you are delivering static content, cloudfront can help you, by caching copies in regions lowering latency. But looking at your description it doesn't seems to be the case.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are transformations that are potentially expensive on the assets at the time of request.  Cloudfront caches the transformations for a contextually relevant period of time.  Don't want to be rude, but I'm looking for an answer to the problem that Cloudfront introduces, not a design critique.

Comment: Is the error occuring on the initial response?  ie-  you make a request to a cloudfront url, and expect a response to an S3 url but are getting the xml error - or are you getting the error when you follow the S3 returned response url?  Be helpful to include a fiddler (or equivalent) trace...